# How to reset factory data programmatically in Android

Tags: android, shell

How to do *Android* device factory data reset from application level?

I tried to run command with `su`, but it's not working. I have tried two ways:

- 1)

  ```
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      try {
          Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "–wipe_data" });
          proc.waitFor();
      } catch (Exception ex) {}
  }
  ```
- 2) when clicking a button, I'm calling device setting application, but I also did't get factory data reset.

  ```
  startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 0);
  ```

  How to call `settings->storage&reset->factory data reset` directly from my app?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [Intent.ACTION_MASTER_CLEAR](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/master/src/com/android/settings/MasterClearConfirm.java#123) to factory reset from your application. You might need to have appropriate permissions for your app (system/signed) to do this.

In case you don't have the required permissions / it's not possible for your app to get to the appropriate permission level, as an alternate, using `am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MASTER_CLEAR` from `su` shell might work.

Comment: Im very sorry.Could you please elaborate.I could not able to understand.

Comment: using `adb shell`, you can connect to a debuggable android device, `am` is a command line tool that comes with android and let's you call verious android commands. the one in the answer let's you broadcast an ACTION_MASTER_CLEAR intent, which will factroy reset the android device.

Comment: In your code, try changing `-wipe_data` to the `am broadcast` command I've given.